# Why can't I use a ValueType[] extension method

Tags: c#

I can use a ValueType extension method with

```
public static string ToStringN(this ValueType value)
{
    return Convert.ToString(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

But I can't use an extension method of a ValueType array.

```
public static void FastReverse(this ValueType[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        ValueType tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.Length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing here?

Comment: What do you mean can use and can't use?

Comment: Is FastReverse in a static class?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to use this on a `int[]` or something similar? Arrays are only covariant when the element type conversion is representation preserving. int to ValueType is not such a conversion because it requires boxing. The solution is to make FastReverse generic rather than using a base type.

Comment: Why do you wish to constrain your algorithm to value types in the first place? Your code would work on arrays of any type, not just arrays of value types, if you wrote it using unconstrained generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, this works:

```
public static string ToStringN(this ValueType value)
{
    return Convert.ToString(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

// usage:
int a = 10;
a.toStringN();
```

This is because `int` is a `ValueType`, so whatever extension method a `ValueType`, `int` has it too.

However, if you do an extension method of a `ValueType[]`,

```
public static void FastReverse(this ValueType[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        ValueType tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.Length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

// usage:
int[] a = {1,2,3};
a.FastReverse(); // Can't find this method!
```

This is because `int[]` and `ValueType[]` are not subtypes of each other. For example, this does not compile:

```
ValueType[] a = new int[10];
```

A workaround is to use generics and constraint the parameter to be `struct`:

```
public static void FastReverse<T>(this T[] arr) where T: struct
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        T tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.Length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

This might not be exactly the behaviour you intended, as it does not work with `int?[]`.

Comment: It is not clear to me why the original poster wishes to constrain this to value types in the first place; there is no code here that would not work on arbitrary T.

Comment: @Sweeper I understand.To quote Eric Lippert 's comments,the method without constraint will work with any type.Ths a lot.